# Как правильно задать определенную ширину в @media запросе без min и max?

Tags: css, mobile

Всем привет! Как правильно задать определенные стили css в @media запросе для конкретной ширины 768 без min и max?

Comment: А можно узнать, для чего требуется ровно 768 пикселей? А то это как-то странно.

Comment: Потому что необходимо совместить диапазоны вида:
собакаmedia (min-width: 767px) and (max-width: 1200px) {...}
собакаmedia (max-width: 768px)  {...}

Answer (score 1):

Внезапно `@media (width: 768px)` будет работать так, как вы заказываете. Но только это вряд ли то, что вам нужно — это не ширина экрана, а ширина активной области в браузере, которая зависит от кучи факторов:

- ориентация экрана;
- размер окна;
- толщина полос прокрутки;
- масштаб;
- и др.

Короче, делать так крайне не рекомендуется, потому что, даже если это вдруг сработает, решение будет очень хрупким. Гораздо лучше задать диапазон, в рамках которого дизайн вашей страницы отображается корректно.

Comment: а если в диапазон попадает 768, которая ни туда (до 768) ни сюда (после 768)
ответ выше для сего мне это

Answer (score 0):

Конкретной ширины не бывает. Окно браузера может иметь любую ширину, кроме нулевой и отрицательной - привыкайте.

Comment: причем тут ваш ответ? вы наверное сути вопроса не поняли: мне нужно задать стили для ширины экрана 768, ни больше ни меньше

Comment: только так:
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 768px)
или есть способ поизящнее?

Comment: изящнее только `@media (width: 768px)` работает? нет? можно же попробовать по логике

Comment: попробовать можно, но проверить сложно: в файле стилей более 10тыс строк кода, делаю рефакторинг и что конкретно из стилей подпадает в размер 768 мне выяснить тяжело, т.к. над проектом работает много людей и мне нужно знать наверняка правильную конструкцию, чтобы ничего не поломалось